# colour sets for Chart.js border colour

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am trying to set specific colours to be used for the borders on my line chart because at the moment I am only able to randomise this:

```
var randomColorGenerator = function () { 
    return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8); 
};

newDataset = { 
    label: data[i].firstName+' '+data[i].lastName, 
    borderColor: randomColorGenerator(), 
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
    data: tmpscore, 
};
```

The idea is to have like a set of colours because the random colours do not match the theme I have created and wondered if there was a way to select randomly from a pool of colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick :

```js
var colorArray = [["#FF4000", false], ["#81BEF7", false], ["#5882FA", false], 
                 ["#04B404", false], ["#A901DB", false], ["#F5A9BC", false]];

// The following makes sure you don't use the same color twice for your datasets
var color;
while (true) {
    var test = colorArray[parseInt(Math.random() * 6)];
    if (!test[1]) {
        color = test[0];
        colorArray[colorArray.indexOf(test)][1] = true;
        break;
    }
}

newDataset = { 
    label: data[i].firstName+' '+data[i].lastName, 
    borderColor: color, 
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
    data: tmpscore, 
};
```

You basically create an array of the colors you want (which fit your style) and randomly use one of them in your dataset.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer man, it seem to just make them all grey now?

Comment: @PhpDude It should be fixed now, I forgot to make the random into an integer

Comment: Thats awesome, one LAST thing, is there way to take the random colour but only use it once, is that doable?

Comment: @PhpDude You mean using a different color for each bar ?

Comment: Yeah, so like not duplicate colours as sometimes itll pick all the lines to be green sometimes by random

Comment: @PhpDude Does [this script](https://jsfiddle.net/myrv8sv2/) suit your needs ? It randomly chooses between a single color from your style and all of them -- If I'm wrong, tell me what you actually want, I think I didn't get what you asked me

Comment: That looks like its doing the right thing on the fiddle but when I do the same to mine it just makes them all the same colours - yours was randomising the borders but duoing them sometimes this one just randomises the colours but all the borders are the same

Comment: @PhpDude Just remove the if/else part at line 11 and keep the inner-else code. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/myrv8sv2/1/)

Comment: they are all just grey now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133537/discussion-between-tektiv-and-phpdude).